# Adding new aggregations to a time series database

Tags: database, postgresql, time-series

I'm implementing a database system in postgresql to support fast queries about time series data from users. Events are for example: User U executed action A at time T. Different event types are split into different tables, currently around 20. As the number of events currently are around 20M and will reach 1B pretty soon, I decided to create aggregation tables. The aggregations are for example: How many users executed at least one action at a particular day, or total number of actions executed each day.

I have created insert triggers that inserts data into the aggregation tables whenever a row is inserted into the event tables. This works great and offers great performance with the current amount of events, and I think it should scale good to.

However, if I want to create a new aggregation only events from that point forward would be aggregated. To have all the old events included, they would have to be re-inserted. I see two ways this could be achieved. The first is to create a "re-run" function that essentially does the following:

1. Find all the tables this aggregation depends on, and all tables those aggregation depends on etc. until you have all direct and indirect dependencies.
2. Copy the tables to temporary tables
3. Empty the tables and the aggregation tables.
4. Re-insert data from the temporary tables.

This poses some questions about atomicity. What if an event is inserted after copying? Should one lock all the tables involved during this operation?

The other solution would be to keep track, for each aggregation table, which rows in the event tables that has been aggregated, and then at some point aggregate all the event that is missing from that track table. This seems to me less prone to concurrency errors, but requires a  lot of tracking storage.

Are there any other solutions, and if not, which of the above would you choose?

Comment: Have you thought of using a TSDB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database or ELK stack to keep track of these events?